# Not able to compare the vector data

Tags: java, collections, vector, hashtable

I want to compare the vector values present in hashtable with other vector,if the vector values are same i want ot perform some operation else i have to perform a save,but i always get the vector values in both are different.i cannot use generics as i am working on old project.

```
Hashtable hCompareTable = rUtil.getEventForComparing(dateSel,e.getTimeZone(),listUserEvents);

Enumeration eventsCompareKey = hCompareTable.keys();

  while (eventsCompareKey.hasMoreElements()) {
        String compareKey = (String) eventsCompareKey.nextElement();
        Vector compareEventData = (Vector) hCompareTable.get(compareKey);

        if (compareKey.equals(dateSel)) {
               for (int i = 0; i < compareEventData.size(); i++) {
         EventData eCompare = (EventData) compareEventData.elementAt(i);
                       for (int j = 0; j < object.size(); j++) {
                                 EventData eveObject = (EventData) object.elementAt( j )
                                       if (eveObject.getSummary().equals(eCompare.getSummary())) {
                                             syso("equal")
                                        }
                                       else{
                                          //do something
                                       }
```

I am not getting how ill i compare the data in both the vectors ,bot the vectors has EventData bean values.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you are comparing always with `lastElement` of the `object` Vector? You are iterating through the size of object but always using last element of the vector object.

Other wise you may require a change to it as:

```
EventData eveObject = (EventData) object.elementAt( j ); // object.lastElement();
```

Comment: even though i use elementAt(j) it wont give me proper result,i just changed to lastElement for testing @Ravinder

Comment: @harqs - add to your post, some sample data you added to `object` and `compareEventData` Vector instances and print summary values to debug.

Comment: object has few summary data like a,b,c and compareEventData also has the same.When i debug the loop gets entered into both equal and not equal sometimes.

Comment: @harqs - show us a) what you added, b) sysout with eventData id and summary for each data object. *not equal sometimes* will not give us a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Does EventData properly overrides Object.equals(Object) method?

Comment: i have not overridden the equals method

Comment: Ok, and where did EventData class implementation cames from? Is it a class made by you? If it is we must implement equals method so that equals method can work: different EventData instances with same internal data must return true when we do eventData1.equals(eventData2);. Or at least same thinking must be applied to the object returned in eveObject.getSummary().

Comment: ok i have created the EventData class which is a bean class with event information,how should be the equals method implementation be defined?

Comment: Probably we don't have to override EventData.equals(). Which Object type is returned for EventData.getSummary()? Is it a String or another object whose implementation is provided by you? Maybe that's the object where we miss equals(Object) method implementation. Wanna share it with us?

Comment: public class EventData implements Persistable {
 EventData() {
 }

 private String startDate;
 private String startTime;
 private String endTime;
 private String userDate;
 private String endDate;
 private String summary;
 private String location;
 private String timezone;
 private String startHr;
 private String endHr;
 private String exactStartDate;
 private String exactEndDate;
 private boolean isAllDay = false;
 private String frequency;
 private int interval;
 private Vector day_of_week;
 private String week_of_the_month;

Comment: i have added the eventdata class sample,what should be done now?

Comment: I suggest you put the code in the question area and not in this comments area. Also please try Ravinder suggestion below: print the summary value before comparing to see what's going on with the data: System.out.println("eveObject.getSummary()="+eveObject.getSummary() + ", eCompare.getSummary()="+eCompare.getSummary());

Comment: eveObject.getSummary()=A1,eCompare.getSummary()=A1